# Check if there's a current pip installation in the background on specific venv

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

I have a jenkins job that runs 100 builds- each 10 builds are in parallel.
Every build should use the venv I created.

I would like to create the venv only at the first build and use it in the other builds.
Since there are 10 builds in parallel - it will try to install the pip package 10 times in parallel at the first iteration.

Right now I'm doing something like this:

```
if [ -d "/home/jenkins/temp/venv_upgrade" ] 
then
    echo "VENV: Directory /home/jenkins/temp/venv_upgrade exists." 
    # Activating the venv
    echo "VENV: Activating the venv"
    source /home/jenkins/temp/venv_upgrade/bin/activate
else
    echo "VENV: Directory /home/jenkins/temp/venv_upgrade does not exists. Creating and Installing VENV there."
    # Creating a new Python3 virtual environment
    echo "VENV: Creating a venv"
    python3.8 -m venv /home/jenkins/temp/venv_upgrade
    
    # Activating the venv
    echo "VENV: Activating the venv"
    source /home/jenkins/temp/venv_upgrade/bin/activate
    
    # Installing project's requirements
    echo "VENV: Installing project's requirements"
    pip3 install -r $WORKSPACE/src/requirements.txt
fi
```

**How can I check from every build if theres a pip installation happening at the current moment on the same venv?**

Comment: *"Right now I'm doing something like this:"* And does it work?

Comment: No- because I as said - _"Since there are 10 builds in parallel - it will try to install the pip package 10 times in parallel at the first iteration."_